# HP 3130 - Recover Windows 7 from Recovery WIM

Tags: windows-7, partitioning

Got a new PC, HP 3130 and didn't get to create the recovery disk.  I did save the recovery partition using imagex to an external hard drive.  I was planning to use a previous image I had and that failed so attempted to put back the recovery partition.  It boots oaky, go into restore manager but fails when attempting to re-create the partitions.

"Recovery manager could not restore your computer using factory image". Please contact HP support.  Error code 0xe0ef0003"

Any ideas?  I think it's something to do with the WINPE environment and partitioning.

Answer (score 0):

Try booting to the external drive.  Once you turn on your computer, you should see instructions to go to a boot menu...

Another alternative, is to check for drive errors.  Try using chkdsk.

Comment: can boot from external drive ok.  using WAIK PE for imagex.  no drive error on chdsk.  thanks